# How to set JAMSHELL in Boost Build/b2/bjam

Tags: shell, visual-c++, bjam, boost-build, b2

The documentation mentions the variable [JAMSHELL](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#jam.language.variables.builtins.jamshell) which allows changing the shell that b2 uses to execute commands. But when I set it in my jamroot it seems that it has no effect.

I use the MSVC compiler.

Example:

```
JAMSHELL = cmddd /C % ; # cmddd is not a shell on my computer so should break b2 but it does not
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject it into the module `msvc`:

```
using msvc : 14.2 ; # you probably already have this line if using MSVC
import modules ;
modules.poke msvc : JAMSHELL : cmddd /C % ;
```

[source](https://lists.boost.org/boost-build/2008/04/18919.php)